# Reoccuring connectivity issue, can't access sites yet steam and skype works

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, internet-connection

Please read all details before posting answers, thank you!

So this issue occurred for the second time since a bit earlier this year. Here is the issue in essence:

Steam and skype works, but dropbox and google drive stops syncing. Both chrome and firefox "stop working", but in a special way. You see, if I try to access a new site, the load circle occurs, BUT it lasts of only a split second, and there is no page loading, at all! Happens in both browsers. Have not tested IE, but still...

What I've done:

I tested with doing a ping to some newspaper site using URL, not IP. Worked fine. I flushed DNS "just in case", no dice. Tried error search of network, nothing. Then disabling and enabling the network card, still nothing. I also checked event logs for any indicators, nothing turned up. The first time I even ran a virus scan cause it scared the crap out of me, but that turned out with nothing. Oh, and that is 3 separate software: MSE, Malwarebytes and Super anti spyware.

Reset both browsers as well, but to no effect. It just suddenly happens. A reboot of the entire PC works, but I don't wanna sit and reboot every time my network goes to hell like... this! I know it's not the router cause net works on all other devices. This is a local, on the PC, issue.

So... Anyone got even a slight idea what this might be?

It's wired connection by the way.

Comment: I have often had issues like these just before my router craps out for good. Existing TCP connections continue to work fine, but new connections cannot be established. NAT routers have a number of facilities related to the creation of a TCP connection, so there could be a failure in any of them. or it could be that the router is not passing dns information as it should. is your router in good working order? does powercycling it when the problems occur resolve the issue, at least temporarily?

Comment: It is strange if it's the router, when net works on all other PC's...

Comment: Try to update network drivers. Btw are you using cable or wifi connection ?

Comment: I must admit I find it funny that people ask questions to me that are already covered in my answer. It's wired, does not have WiFi card in it as it's a stationary machine. I will see if there are drivers to update for the card, but what I hope for is an answer to exactly WHY it happens. It may not ever happen again, or it may suddenly become a serious, repeating issue. In short, I hope someone had a similar issue, able to pin-point the exact reason. Because I don't want it to happen while I am in the middle of something.

Comment: Even the engineers that designed and build the equipment you are using would require a lot of work with specialized debugging and analysis tools to determine the exact cause of your issue microscopically. All anyone on this site can do is help you look for macroscopic configuration issues and fixes, and the process for that may not be exactly what you want to hear. personally, I still think the issue is with your router, and yes, I did read your bit about other devices. PCs and phones use data connections rather differently, (phones tend to sip data, rather than slurp it like PCs).

Comment: I can understand that, but what I hope for at least, is perhaps someone who've had the same issue that can confirm they did something that seems to have kept it from happening again.